# Template html not rendering correctly

Tags: django, django-templates

When I try to view the template I created the development server shows the template html file as if it were plain text.  Basically the web page shows what is in my template .html file.  I know something is working because when I pass the render_to_response function the dictionary of arguments and try to display the variable I passed I it renders that part correctly.  Here is an example of the problem.

This is the template file:

`<b>Hello</b>`

Then the output source code is the following:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
`<html>`
`<head>`
  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">`
  `<title></title>`
 `<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">`
`<meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1038.35">`
`<style type="text/css">`
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Courier}
`</style>`

`</head>`
`<body>`
`<p class="p1">&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;</p>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

And the screen just shows:
 `<b>Hello</b>`

Any ideas on how to make my template render as if it were an html file would be appreciated.

Comment: `&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;` is `<b>Hello</b>`.  That's what your template says to display.  It works great.

Comment: You're not explaining this properly. If your template file is just `<b>Hello</b>` then where's all that doctype stuff coming from? You need to show exactly what the template is, and how you're rendering it in the view.

Comment: @daniel.  Maybe I'm just confused at what the template does.  This is my view function: def start(request, foo):
    return render_to_response('code_user.html', {"foo":foo}). And if the template file is: <b>{{foo}}</b> the output on the screen when I load the web page is `<b>foo</b>` where foo is the value of the variable. What I'm not sure of is where the doctype stuff is coming from.  I guess that's my real question.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how you're outputting the html file into your template, but, if you're doing something like this in your template

```
{{ my_template }}
```

to render the my_template string variable that you're passing to render_to_response

you just need to use the [safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe) filter

```
{{ my_template|safe }}
```

this won't html-encode your string, and the html will render propery into your page